# Get latitude and longitude from address not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic3

i am used nativegeocoder plugin to get latitude and longitude . it working perfectly single input. it not working perfectly for loop .

```
    this.JobsVals = [];   this.database.selectjobsvaltable().then((data) => {
    var item = {} as any;

    item = data;
    this.items = item;
    if (this.items != null && this.items.length > 0) {
      for (var index = 0; index < this.items.length; index++) {
        if (this.items[index].checkedvalues == "1" || this.items[index].checkedvalues == "1.0") {
          this.items[index].checkedvalues = "1";
          for(let i = index; i< this.data_obj.length;i++){

          let address = this.data_obj[i].addr +this.data_obj[i].addr1+','+this.data_obj[i].city+','+this.data_obj[i].state;

          this.getAddress(address);
          let addlat = {'name':this.data_obj[i].fullname,'address':address,'lat':this.global.lat,'lon':this.global.lon,'jival':this.data_obj[i].jivalue};
          this.locationArray.push(addlat);
            console.log(this.locationArray);
            break;
          }
          this.job = {
            agencyid: this.items[index].agencyID,
            cvalue: this.items[index].cvalue,
            caseno: this.items[index].caseno,
            cco: this.items[index].cco,
            dvalue: this.items[index].dvalue,
            documents: this.items[index].documents,
            dohttppost: this.items[index].dohttppost,
            dohttppostip: this.items[index].dohttppostip,
            email: this.items[index].email,
            emailphotoid: this.items[index].emailphotoid,
            fullname: this.items[index].fullname,
            jivalue: this.items[index].jivalue,
            lawfirmjobref: this.items[index].lawfirmjobref,
            pvalue: this.items[index].pvalue,
            subserverid: this.items[index].subserverid,
            checkedvalues: "1"

          };
          this.storage.set("mapArray",JSON.stringify(this.locationArray));
          console.log("Map Array :"+this.storage.get("mapArray"))
          this.JobsVals.push(this.job);
          localStorage.setItem("jobsarray", JSON.stringify(this.items));
        }
        if(index == this.items.length-1){
          localStorage.setItem("selectedjobsarray", JSON.stringify(this.JobsVals));
          this.navCtrl.push(MapPage,this.locationArray);
        }
      }
    } else {

      this.navCtrl.push(MapPage, this.locationArray);
    }   }, (error) => {   });


getAddress(address){   let options: NativeGeocoderOptions = {
    useLocale: true,
    maxResults: 5 };   this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(address, options)   .then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult[]) =>{   this.global.lat = coordinates[0].latitude;   this.global.lon = coordinates[0].longitude;

  console.log("lat:"+this.global.lat);   console.log("lon:"+this.global.lon);  }) .catch((error: any) => console.log(error)); }
```

if i set delay methode i will get last address lat,lon for all address. else it show undefined. i declare lat and lon is global variable in my code . may i don't where is the problem

Comment: can you try to make your code readable? i.e. indentation is random at the moment

Comment: `0: {name: "test", address: "sravanampatti,,TN", lat: undefined, lon: undefined, jival: "6"}
1: {name: "test3", address: "Triplicane,Chennai,TN", lat: undefined, lon: undefined, jival: "7"}`

Comment: now i add full code

Comment: and it's still hard to read due to it being **poorly formatted** - nobody asked for *more code* ... I asked for *readable code*

Comment: and you still have an unconditional `break` at the end of `for(let i = index; i< this.data_obj.length;i++){` ... so why loop at all, if `i` can only ever be `index` and nothing else

Comment: `this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode` is asynchronous and you are not waiting for it to finish before using the values it creates ... don't expect to use `this.global.lat` etc correctly in asynchronous code - one loop will overwrite the previous loop, and because of asynchrony, you'll never have the right values when you want them

Comment: okay... now i understood my problem... sorry for waste your time. i am an native android developer. i am new in ionic. that's why it happen... thanks a lot

Comment: wasn't wasting my time dude